# Access to select input displayed text - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, selected

I'm using Angula 9 and I have a mat-select input in a ReactiveForm. I want to show the selected option - not the input value - outside my form, inside the same html template.

I'm doing this:

```
<div class="basic-container">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-label>Category*</mat-label>
        <mat-select type="text" aria-label="Number" formControlName="category">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of categories" [value]="option.id">
                <p>{{option.name}}</p>
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>
</div>

<p>{{myForm.value.category}}</p>
```

Any idea how to reach the option displayed and not the input value?

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want to achieve

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible to use the displayed text. However, you can change your value to contain the option `[value]="option"`. You need to obtain the `id` then when parsing the form:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select type="text" aria-label="Number" formControlName="category">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of categories" [value]="option">
      <p>{{option.name}}</p>
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>{{myForm.value.category.name}}</p>
```

Or if you don't want to do that, you can use a function to get the correct category:

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select type="text" aria-label="Number" formControlName="category">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let option of categories" [value]="option.id">
      <p>{{option.name}}</p>
     </mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<p>{{getCategoryById(myForm.value.category)}}</p>
```

```
getCategoryById(categoryId: number): Category {
  return this.categories.find(({ id }) => id === categoryId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @poul. I'd go for your second option, the problem is that I have a "huge" form with 30 inputs. Each input calls an API service to fullfil the input options/information. And at the end, before submitting the form, I want the user to confirm the form after a complete overview of what he had selected. So, maybe, if I use a function for each 30 inputs, is not so efficient, right?

Comment: @4aLifeTime as long as you are using `OnPush` as change detection strategy, there is nothing to worry about. Even without it, it's just a simple array look up which short circuits when it find a match. It's incomparable to the amount of functions angular executes in the background